# Pop up slider not working in IE. What is wrong in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys please [check this page](http://girisoft.net/louisa/aboutus.html).

Please visit the page using any browser except IE.
Click the 4th bullet. And then click "the hogc story" link. You can see one popup slider.

Now visit the page using IE. popup slider not working there. It only shows black screen. What is wrong in my code?. [Here is my code](http://pastebin.com/dMiSRSbS)  
Thanks

Comment: Does not work in FF5.01!

Comment: But i see its working in FF5.0

Comment: http://i52.tinypic.com/2rh9sn7.jpg

Comment: I upgraded my firefox to 5.0.1 and i see its working. But my problem is its not working in IE. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE9 on Windows 7, In your code under

```
 <div class="slider nivoSlider>
```

the images are getting inline styles of

```
display: none;
```

If I disable this manually, the content is visible. I suspect the Javascript/JQuery responsible for this is not working propely. See the image

[image]

Additionally you should add the Javascript and JQuery tags to this question as I suspect the fault lies there.

Comment: +1, Thanks jawad, I really appreciate you help. Let me add tags

Comment: @Viruthagiri: I don't think adding the tags now is going to help much. I suggest you post a new question with the Javascript and JQuery tags added along with html and CSS. Close this question first by accepting it. Your new question will show up at the top and newer people will be able to help you. Message me with the link when you have posted the new question. Also add IE9 tag

Comment: Added new question here as per your suggestion. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723030/pop-up-slider-not-working-in-ie-some-javascript-interfering-css-code-please-hel