# Pop up slider not working in IE. Some javascript interfering css code. Please help me

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys please [check this page](http://girisoft.net/louisa/aboutus.html).

Please visit the page using any browser except IE. Click the 4th bullet. And then click "the hogc story" link. You can see one popup slider.

Now visit the page using IE. popup slider not working there. It only shows black screen. What is wrong in my code?. [Here is my code](http://pastebin.com/dMiSRSbS) Thanks.
Special thanks to [Jawad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/731043/jawad) for the screenshot.
[image]

This is what he found out in my code.

In IE9 on Windows 7, In your code under

```
<div class="slider nivoSlider>
```

the images are getting inline styles of

```
display: none;
```

So can anyone tell me how to fix this problem.? I have no idea which javascript causing this problem in IE. Its working fine in all other browsers.
Thanks

Comment: You could really do with cleaning up your html. Especially the extra line breaks and indentation. It is not very well organised and if possible you should have your all javascript in seperate files. It would make it much easier to find the code and therefore the problem.

Comment: I separated js,css codes from html file. You can see the source now. HTML source - http://pastebin.com/uZRNLv3B  CSS source:  http://pastebin.com/M6hf13ap JS source: http://pastebin.com/E0jhmUcH

Comment: I fixed it by myself. The slider what i'm using is nivoslider. Height need to defined there to make it work in IE.This is what i applied in my code.  

    .slider {
    position:relative;
    width: 1280px;
    height: 412px;
    background: url(../images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    }    PS: I couldn't post it as answer since i dont have 100 reputation

Comment: @Viruthagiri: Great find. Problem was in CSS after all!

Comment: @Jawad Yep. Problem was in CSS

Comment: @Viruthagiri: You should put your solution in an answer below and mark it as accepted. It won't get you any points but it lets people know the answer plus they can vote you up if they think it is a good answer.

Comment: @te16 My problem is i have low reputation. So i couldn't post answer myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by myself. The slider what i'm using is nivoslider. Height need to defined there to make it work in IE.This is what i applied in my code.

`.slider { position:relative; 
width: 1280px; 
height: 412px; 
background: url(../images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%; }`